# Where are the public PPE contracts between Hinpack and the UK government?

Tags: united-kingdom, covid-19

Matt Hancock insists no contract between the government and his ex-pub-landlord's company Hinpack exists as part of the Covid PPE procurement rounds.

The [Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/politics/2021/dec/01/matt-hancock-says-labours-covid-contract-claims-rubbish) states that

> However, the contract which is between Alpha and the secretary of state for health, and signed by a civil servant on his behalf in December 2020, stipulated that all the work would be subcontracted to Hinpack, the Guardian revealed earlier this year.

It's my understanding that these contracts are supposed to be made public. Where are these contracts published? And does the subcontracting clause stipulating the use of Hinpack exist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contracts are available (when eventually published) on the [GOV.UK contracts finder website](https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/Search) - [this contract](https://www.contractsfinder.service.gov.uk/notice/3390c018-8195-44dd-9d87-28fcb8bfecfa) is the one you refer to between Alpha Laboratories Ltd. & The Secretary of State for Health and Social Care (then Matt Hancock).

The [published contract pdf](https://atamis-1928.cloudforce.com/sfc/p/#0O000000rwim/a/4J000000kF3q/OhSVRsdVD3LrSEJblaw_AKBOSFB3K23cnaTfTQILAbk) redacts the name of the company referred to in the subcontracting clause:

> **7.3 Subcontracting**
> The Authority agrees and acknowledges that the Supplier will sub-contract manufacture of the Goods to [REDACTED]
> and that it shall be deemed to have given consent to such
> sub-contracting for the purposes of Clause 28.1 of the Call Off Terms
> and Conditions.

However, Jolyon Maugham of the Good Law Project [has published](https://twitter.com/JolyonMaugham/status/1465927760069672961) what he alleges to be an unredacted copy of the contract on Twitter which shows Hinpack Ltd. as the redacted sub-contracting party.